# Docking the buttons at the bottom

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to dock the 2 buttons at the bottom of the window, so that they are always there when I resize the window. Obviously I am doing it wrong since it won't work. Here is my code. I have also seen from examples that some people uses the DockPanel.Dock on the controls and not the container itself. I can't do this for some reason. Using DockPanel.dock on the button gives an error.

My question is: How do I make the buttons (Or the stackPanel) dock at bottom?

```
<Window x:Class="MeditCal.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">      
        <Grid>                              
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />                                       
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>                

           <Label Grid.Row="0">Date</Label>
           <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Name="DateTxtBox" Background="WhiteSmoke"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2">Note</Label>
           <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Name="noteTxtBox" 
                    Background="WhiteSmoke"></TextBox>               
        </Grid>
        <Popup Height="100" Width="100" Name="popUpWin" StaysOpen="false" 
               AllowsTransparency="True" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" PopupAnimation="Fade">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="AliceBlue">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Record added" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
        <ListView Name="msgArea" Background="WhiteSmoke" MinHeight="150" 
                  Height="138"  />            
    </StackPanel>        

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button Name="addButton" Content="Add" Grid.Column="0" 
                        Grid.Row="1" />
                <Button Name="getRecordsButton" Content="Get records" 
                        Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>

        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear what kind of layout you're trying to achieve. I would suggest you to remove the inner `DockPanel` and it's `StackPanel` child, because each of them only contains single child which is an indication that you don't need a panel wrapper there.

Something like this will make the `Grid` containing buttons placed at bottom, and the `StackPanel` fill remaining space in the `DockPanel` :

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Name="addButton" Content="Add" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Button Name="getRecordsButton" Content="Get records" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel>      
        <Grid>                              
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />                                       
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>                

           <Label Grid.Row="0">Date</Label>
           <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Name="DateTxtBox" Background="WhiteSmoke"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2">Note</Label>
           <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Name="noteTxtBox" Background="WhiteSmoke"></TextBox>               
        </Grid>
        <Popup Height="100" Width="100" Name="popUpWin" StaysOpen="false" AllowsTransparency="True" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" PopupAnimation="Fade">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="AliceBlue">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Record added" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
        <ListView Name="msgArea" Background="WhiteSmoke" MinHeight="150" Height="138"  />            
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your help solved the docking problem.
I want the ListView to be in middle (which it already is), and to take rest of the space. Right now if I drag the window, the listview will stop eventually, cus it has a static height. Using the verticalAlignment="strech" is fine, but I am forced to also give it a minHegiht, or else it will be very small at start

Comment: So this particular docking problem solved and now you have another problem.. I'd suggest to open new question for the other problem